# Have react native send message to localhost computer server

Tags: android, node.js, express, react-native

I have a react native app that a want to send a post request to my localhost server on my windows computer. The server is using express. It works for the react site version, but the message won't go through for the app.

```
    fetch('http://35.3.52.25:3000/', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {

          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({ 'text': this.state.results }),
      })
      .then(function(res){ console.log(res) })
      .catch(function(res){ console.log(res) })
```

hear is the code and I get no response from the server

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please post the procedure you're following and the code you're using. Also, if there is any error message, also post that.

Comment: Just updated, @GCSDC.

Comment: What do you mean by "It works for the react site version, but the message won't go through for the app."? Also, if you're sending a request to localhost, you should possibly be using `'localhost'` as the url.